# How can I pass parameters to token filter script in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, parameters, token

I want to do something like the one below, but this code clearly does not work. Is there any way I can pass a predefined parameter to the "source" section?

```
term_temp = "of kerosene, kerosene fuel"
predicate_token_filter_temp = {
        "type" : "predicate_token_filter",
    "script" : {
        "source": "String additional_terms = term_path ;String curr_token = toke n.getTerm().toString(); !curr_token.contains(\" \") || additional_terms.contains(curr_token);",
        "params": {"term_path": term_temp }
    }
```

}